# How can I position my divs so that my site is compatible with more browsers?

Tags: css, cross-browser

My site is "off" when I open it on a different computer. The text in the menu bar, the sub menu, the bottom, the left text, all of that is pushed down or up or to the side? Any ideas of how to make it compatible on different browsers? Is it worth the effort? Should I assume that my users are going to have the latest versions, because my target audience are college students?

url:http://arabic001.com

Comment: Welcome to being a web developer.

Comment: Definitely worth the effort for your site, since when I downsize my window your site is totally unusable.

Comment: What browsers and version are you talking about? If it's IE <= 7 I would say screw dem, same for FF< 3 but I never had compatibility problems with FF

Comment: Since the question was closed, let me at least suggest changing your `wrapper` from `position: absolute` to `relative` and using `margin: 0 auto` to center it. This at least made the site usable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important thing is to write markup that validates against the Doctype you defined. You can e.g. use the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) or the [HTML Validator](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/html-validator/) firefox plugin. That way you can make fairly sure that it looks similar in most of the modern browsers, meaning you will only have to deal with IE < 9.

Comment: I found a number of errors using W3C Validator and I am working on them. Many thanks.